# Why has Red Hat Cluster Suite stopped working?

Tags: centos, redhat, cluster, rhcs

I've been testing the Cluster Suite on CentOS 6.4, and had it working fine, but I noticed today [**8th August, when this question was originally asked**] that it's not liking the config that was previously working. I tried to recreate a configuration from scratch using CCS, but that gave validation errors.

---

**Edited 21st August:**

I've now reinstalled the box completely from CentOS 6.4 x86_64 minimal install, adding the following packages and their dependencies:

```
yum install bind-utils dhcp dos2unix man man-pages man-pages-overrides nano nmap ntp rsync tcpdump unix2dos vim-enhanced wget
```

and

```
yum install rgmanager ccs
```

The following commands all worked:

```
ccs -h ha-01 --createcluster test-ha
ccs -h ha-01 --addnode ha-01
ccs -h ha-01 --addnode ha-02
ccs -h ha-01 --addresource ip address=10.1.1.3 monitor_link=1
ccs -h ha-01 --addresource ip address=10.1.1.4 monitor_link=1
ccs -h ha-01 --addresource ip address=10.110.0.3 monitor_link=1
ccs -h ha-01 --addresource ip address=10.110.8.3 monitor_link=1
ccs -h ha-01 --addservice routing-a autostart=1 recovery=restart
ccs -h ha-01 --addservice routing-b autostart=1 recovery=restart
ccs -h ha-01 --addsubservice routing-a ip ref=10.1.1.3
ccs -h ha-01 --addsubservice routing-a ip ref=10.110.0.3
ccs -h ha-01 --addsubservice routing-b ip ref=10.1.1.4
ccs -h ha-01 --addsubservice routing-b ip ref=10.110.8.3
```

and resulted in the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cluster config_version="13" name="test-ha">
    <fence_daemon/>
    <clusternodes>
        <clusternode name="ha-01" nodeid="1"/>
        <clusternode name="ha-02" nodeid="2"/>
    </clusternodes>
    <cman/>
    <fencedevices/>
    <rm>
        <failoverdomains/>
        <resources>
            <ip address="10.1.1.3" monitor_link="1"/>
            <ip address="10.1.1.4" monitor_link="1"/>
            <ip address="10.110.0.3" monitor_link="1"/>
            <ip address="10.110.8.3" monitor_link="1"/>
        </resources>
        <service autostart="1" name="routing-a" recovery="restart">
            <ip ref="10.1.1.3"/>
            <ip ref="10.110.0.3"/>
        </service>
        <service autostart="1" name="routing-b" recovery="restart">
            <ip ref="10.1.1.4"/>
            <ip ref="10.110.8.3"/>
        </service>
    </rm>
</cluster>
```

However, if I use `ccs_config_validate` or try to start the `cman` service, it fails with:

```
Relax-NG validity error : Extra element rm in interleave
tempfile:10: element rm: Relax-NG validity error : Element cluster failed to validate content
Configuration fails to validate
```

What's going on? This used to work!

Comment: Is your cluster up and running? Is `cman` started on the nodes, what does `clustat` and `cman_tool status` say? (asking because you say that you've recreated the config on a previously running cluster.

Comment: Same result whether the cluster is started or stopped. Doesn't ccs just modify a configuration ready for it to be pushed to the cluster?

Comment: Just ran `ccs_config_validate` on the old config, and got:
`Relax-NG validity error : Extra element rm in interleave` / `tempfile:10: element rm: Relax-NG validity error : Element cluster failed to validate content` / `Configuration fails to validate`

Comment: Same when just adding `<ip address="192.168.1.3"/>` to the newly generated config.

Comment: Does it work without the `<failoverdomains/>` in `<rm>` ?

Comment: No; same failure to validate.

Comment: Just in case ... can you remove any standalone section ?
Like     <fence_daemon/>,     <cman/>,   <fencedevices/>,         <failoverdomains/>

Comment: what version of cman do you have? what is in your  `/var/lib/cluster/cluster.rng`  ?

Comment: Hi, Petter. Was away for a week; sorry. cman is version 3.0.12.1, release 49.el6_4.2; my cluster.rng is at http://pastebin.com/br4pQ5nS, though it's probably never changed from the one installed by yum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just started working again, after more `yum update` dancing. I have compared the old and new `/var/lib/cluster/cluster.rng` and, surprise, surprise, there's a difference. The one on the systems that didn't work was missing any definitions for the `<ip>` element.

The current incarnation of the system was installed from the same minimal CD, and I have a step-by-step procedure of commands to cut and paste, which worked several times while I was developing it, then failed for nearly two months, now starts working again. I've built the box about half a dozen times, so I guess it's not the procedure.

A slip up on Red Hat's part, perhaps, but I'm not sure how to find out what changes were checked into this file in the last two months.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the failover domains, if you wanna define a service on redhat cluster, first you need to define a failoverdomain, you can use a failoverdomain for many services or one per service.

If you need more information about the failover domain "man clurgmgrd"

A failover domain is an ordered subset of members to which a service may be bound. The following

is a list of semantics governing the options  as  to how the different configuration options affect the behavior of a failover domain:

Comment: More info will make this an answer.  Can you add to your answer?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately failoverdomains is an optional element, and this configuration used to work without any.

Comment: at this point i think you have a problem with your ha software version, i valited your xml cluster config and i can tell it works. I use xmllint --relaxng /usr/share/system-config-cluster/misc/cluster.ng cluster.xml for validate

Comment: I don't have a cluster.ng on my system - presumably because it's CentOS 6.4 and system-config-cluster isn't available. Using /var/lib/cluster/cluster.rng fails validation with the "extra element rm in interleave" error.

Comment: @c4f4t0r, would it be helpful to compare the contents of your /usr/share/system-config-cluster/misc/cluster.ng with /var/lib/cluster/cluster.rng on my system, or are they likely to be very different?

Comment: @Iain Hallam good idea, but in this moment i don't have access to my redhat cluster